# Is there any method to avoid duplicate result by looping in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have 2 set of data and i would like to find and match by condition and i do not want my matched result to be repeated if have similar criteria.

data as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020'],
                   'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186', 'opq-468','999-xq','789-44','154-abc','opq-468'],
                   'no': ['36','55','45','77','107','1149','456' ],
                   'result':['','','','','','','']})


df_list = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020'],
                        'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186','789-44','154-abc', 'opq-468','opq-468','123-x'],
                        'complete': ['yes','no','on-going','yes','yes','yes','no' ],
                        'code':['alpha', 'vertical','horizon','grand','empire','jade','roms']})
```

my intention is to match **date**, **complete = 'yes'** and **item in df is same as df_list**, but if there is similar from the result, it will proceed to find next one

i tried below but it keep shows me 2 similar result, and if i add a break, it will not shows the result

```
listrange = []
for i in range(len(df_list)):
    for j in range(len(df)):
        if ((df_list['date'][i] == df['date'][j] ) and (df_list['complete'][i] == 'yes') and (df_list['item'][i] == df['item'][j])):         
            df['result'][j] = df_list['code'][i]
            # break    
print(df)

OUTPUT(1):
         date     item    no result
0  16-04-2020    X-317    36  alpha
1  20-04-2020   ry-186    55       
2  16-04-2020  opq-468    45   jade
3  16-04-2020   999-xq    77       
4  20-04-2020   789-44   107       
5  20-04-2020  154-abc  1149  grand
6  16-04-2020  opq-468   456   jade

OUTPUT(1):        >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> with break in the code
         date     item    no  result
0  16-04-2020    X-317    36   alpha
1  20-04-2020   ry-186    55        
2  16-04-2020  opq-468    45  jade
3  16-04-2020   999-xq    77        
4  20-04-2020   789-44   107        
5  20-04-2020  154-abc  1149   grand
6  16-04-2020  opq-468   456
```

**EXPECTED** result should be as below:

```
         date     item    no  result
0  16-04-2020    X-317    36   alpha
1  20-04-2020   ry-186    55        
2  16-04-2020  opq-468    45  empire
3  16-04-2020   999-xq    77        
4  20-04-2020   789-44   107        
5  20-04-2020  154-abc  1149   grand
6  16-04-2020  opq-468   456  jade
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020'],
                   'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186', 'opq-468','999-xq','789-44','154-abc','opq-468'],
                   'no': ['36','55','45','77','107','1149','456' ],
                   'result':['','','','','','','']})


df_list = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020'],
                        'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186','789-44','154-abc', 'opq-468','opq-468','123-x'],
                        'complete': ['yes','no','on-going','yes','yes','yes','no' ],
                        'code':['alpha', 'vertical','horizon','grand','empire','jade','roms']})

df2 = df.drop('result', axis=1)

yes_ix = df_list[df_list.complete=="yes"].index
df2 = df2.merge(df_list.loc[yes_ix].drop('complete', axis=1), on=["date", "item"], how="left")
df2.rename({"code":"result"}, axis=1, inplace=True)
df2.result = df2.result.fillna("")
print(df2)
```

First, you filter df_list with the "yes" on "complete".

Secondly, you use [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to join the dataframes based on "date" and "item".
The rest is only pure formatting (renaming columns, replacing NaN by empty strings and the like.

Comment: hihi, is there any other method? because this will affect my data in df, df len need to be original and same amount of len before and after matched

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020'],
                   'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186', 'opq-468','999-xq','789-44','154-abc','opq-468'],
                   'no': ['36','55','45','77','107','1149','456' ],
                   'result':['','','','','','','']})


df_list = pd.DataFrame({'date' : ['16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '16-04-2020', '20-04-2020'],
                        'item' : ['X-317', 'ry-186','789-44','154-abc', 'opq-468','opq-468','123-x'],
                        'complete': ['yes','no','on-going','yes','yes','yes','no' ],
                        'code':['alpha', 'vertical','horizon','grand','empire','jade','roms']})

df['id'] = df.groupby(['item']).transform('cumcount')
df = df.drop('result', 1)
df_list['id'] = df_list.groupby(['item']).transform('cumcount')

res = df.merge(df_list[['date', 'item', 'id', 'code']], how='left',
               on=['date', 'item', 'id']).drop('id', 1).rename(columns={'code': 'result'}).fillna('')

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
         date     item    no  result
0  16-04-2020    X-317    36   alpha
1  20-04-2020   ry-186    55        
2  16-04-2020  opq-468    45  empire
3  16-04-2020   999-xq    77        
4  20-04-2020   789-44   107        
5  20-04-2020  154-abc  1149   grand
6  16-04-2020  opq-468   456    jade
```

The idea behind creating the *id* column is to solve the issue of:

> but if there is similar from the result, it will proceed to find next
> one

Note that rows with the same value at the *item* column, will have different *id*. At the same time, the *id* values will allow to match first of each value in *df* with its corresponding on *df_list* and so on.

Comment: hi, i got an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'cumcount'`, is there anything i left out?

Comment: @BBBBBBBB I updated the question with your code for creating the dataframes, I ran this and got no error and the expected output